# Next.js TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hook')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-devtools

This error just "explodes" when starting the app or just update the redux state
sometimes it do not shows for few state updates, but for some reason it appears all along the app

What I tried:

- delete node modules and package-lock.json
- dig up for hours last few days, but unfortunately nothing for my case appear...

One screenshot of the TypeError:

[image: 1]

Here is my package.json

```
  {
  "name": "something-admin",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3000",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "build:export": "next build && next export -o build/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.8.3",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^4.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "firebase": "^8.2.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lodash.range": "^3.2.0",
    "mdi-react": "^7.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "^11.1.0",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.0",
    "next-images": "^1.3.0",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "next-redux-saga": "^4.1.2",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^6.0.2",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "polished": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-notification": "^4.5.4",
    "rc-slider": "^8.7.1",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.7.3",
    "rc-tooltip": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.38.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.3.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.15.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dotdotdot": "^1.3.1",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.4",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.16.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.9.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.4",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
    "react-images": "^1.1.0-beta.3",
    "react-intl": "^5.20.4",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.12",
    "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^8.0.6",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.3",
    "react-table": "^7.6.3",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.7",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.5.3",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "eslint": "7",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update

The problem was coming from "rc-notification"
For some reason the lib was throwing it all over
removing the lib fixed the problem