# next-dev.js:20 TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hook'),

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js13

his error just "explodes" when starting the app or just update the redux state sometimes it do not shows for few state updates, but for some reason it appears all along the app

next-dev.js:20 TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hook'),

I have the same issues as mentioned in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129969/next-js-typeerror-cannot-set-properties-of-undefined-setting-hook`

but my package.json file is different.

below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "abc-reactjs-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"next dev\" \"tailwindcss -i styles/globals.scss -o styles/dist.css -w\"",
    "build": "tailwindcss -m -i styles/globals.scss -o styles/dist.css && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "prettier --check .",
    "setup": "node selectInstallation",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci",
    "format": "prettier . --write"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.4",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "antd": "^5.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "eslint": "8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jotai": "^1.11.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "next": "13.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.3",
    "yup": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Removing node_modules but didn't worked

Error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Put the error log in the question

Comment: Screen shot is now attached

Comment: You may have an infinite error somewhere in your app, try creating a `codesandbox` and see if you can replicate it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error was due to the some malicious chrome extension, i have used the guest chrome browser and the errors are gone.